# After installing couchbase php sdk, php module can not be added

Tags: php, couchbase

As stated in the title, it seems that php-sdk is not applied after installing php-sdk.

i using couchbase community edition 6.0.0 and nginx, php7.0-fpm

And the next one I tried to install php-sdk.

Reference site https://docs.couchbase.com/php-sdk/2.6/start-using-sdk.html

$ wget http://packages.couchbase.com/releases/couchbase-release/couchbase-release-1.0-6-amd64.deb

```
$ dpkg -i couchbase-release-1.0-6-amd64.deb

$ apt-get update

$ apt-get install libcouchbase-dev build-essential php-dev zlib1g-dev

$ pecl install couchbase

$ vi /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini 

  extension=couchbase.so  // add

$ php7.0-fpm & nginx restart
```

> $ php -m
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/couchbase.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/couchbase.so: undefined symbol: json_globals in Unknown on line 0
>
> The following warning is output and couchbase is not added to [php modules]. (json is present)

Tell me what to try
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the reference document you have linked there is a note, that couchbase module depends on JSON module:
[image]

So just follow the documentation, and load `json.so`. Another hint would be to read error message, which is saying that it cannot resolve `json_globals`.

Comment: Thank you
I saw and edited your post on the couchbase official website.

My solution is to add json.so and couchbase.so to etc / php / 7.0 / cli / php.ini in that order I disabled json.so in /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini.

However, phpinfo () did not print couchbase, nor did hello-couchbase.php.


I also added json.so and couchbase.so to etc / php / 7.0 / fpm / php.ini and restarted php, nginx so that couchbase was printed in phpinfo () and hello-couchbase.php also worked.